# node not found when using brackets IDE

Tags: node.js

So i am following along a lynda tutorial video for node.js, and it was suggested to download the node.js binding for brackets so that we can have a terminal inside of brackets to run our node.

However, whenever I try to run I get the following:

```
/bin/sh: node: command not found
Program exited with status code of 127.
```

The terminal path where it is showing its attempt at running node is:

"/Users/userName/Documents/lynda_practice/nodejs/my-module.js". I am at a complete loss as to why this rather poorly documented plugin is incapable of finding node considering that I can run it just fine if i use my mac's terminal. As is seen here, while being located in the same directory:

```
node module-demo.js 
text from module: Hello from module
```

Comment: install package like node-terminal to make every thing easy

Comment: Okay..and how to go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

These are multiple debugger are available in Bracket

[top hundred packages of Bracket](http://brackets.dnbard.com/extensions)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and based on your post I think I'm doing the same Lynda.com training. What I did is I uninstalled Brackets 1.8 and instead installed Brackets 1.7. In Brackets 1.7 I was able to install the Node.js Bindings with the extension manager as they do in the training video. Here is a link to the Brackets 1.7 download: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases/tag/release-1.7

I'm running on Windows 7 and this fixed the problem for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually to clarify: I didn't have the same exact problem, but a similar problem: I couldn't install the Node.js Bindings with the extension manager at all in Brackets 1.8.

Comment: Using it on my mac, so might be why? Will give it a whirl. Like it is not a big deal since i can just use the terminal (nor would be it be a big deal since Win10 has the option of enabling a bash shell).